# PayPal smart button - redirect to PayPal website

Tags: paypal

I use PayPal's smart buttons generator to generate code that will render buttons on my website. This works well and the buttons display properly on my website.

[image: Smart buttons]

Initially, their behaviour was as follows: User clicks on the "Debit or Credit Card" button and they are taken to the PayPal website where the user would enter their card details etc. For me this is the preferred behaviour.

For some reason this behaviour stopped working and now clicking on the button renders and embedded form to enter credit card details within my webpage.

How can I go back to the previous behaviour that would take the user to PayPal website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few countries that aren't eligible for the embedded card form, and so will open the PayPal window as a fallback.

All other users will see the embedded form where available, which is the intended functionality for the button. If you won't want the black button, you can append `&disable-funding=card` to the SDK line, leaving only the regular PayPal experience. There is no way to make the black button open a window, it is not designed or intended to work that way.

The embedded experience is nicer anyway.

Comment: Maybe the embedded experience is nicer, but my website doesn't use secure connection so I prefer user to enter CC details on PayPal side. Are you sure there is no way to achieve this?

Comment: There's no way. But the embedded iframe is https and fully secured.